# Is it possible to seamlessly redirect websockets?

Tags: javascript, nginx, websocket

I know that it is possible to pass requests through the reverse proxy (like Nginx, HAproxy and so on) but I need to redirect requests to another public server in the same domain suffix. I.e. from `wss://example.com` to `wss://ws1.example.com`.
Here is an example:
[image]

I need to redirect requests from Nginx or Java.
Is to possible to organize? Do I need to handle redirects on a client side or this code is enough?

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://example.com");

socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Connection established.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  alert('Connection closed');
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Data: " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Error " + error.message);
};
```

Comment: I think that this depends on client implementation. Most of ws clients does not follow redirect during HTTP handshake..

Comment: Do you know browser client which follow redirects?

Comment: I dont think so. Client could get new location url from response, disconnect and reconnect to new url. I quess that current implementation throws error instead. Maybe some client ws library like socket.io? There is [open issue](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1120) related to following redirect, but without any progress..

Comment: Yes but I don't want to force clients manage this logic. Of course it is a workaround but hope in the future redirection will be supported normally.

Comment: @Oleksandr did you ever get something like this working?

Comment: @JohnBachir I didn't but jfriend00 made a good point about client side redirection logic. In case you are managing both server side and client side code then it's easier to implement than if you are providing general API to your clients. In case you are providing general API it would probably make sense to incorporate some policy which determines your API usage. That said, I didn't have a chance to work on that, so, probably there are better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per the [webSocket specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> Once the client's opening handshake has been sent, the client MUST wait for a response from the server before sending any further data.  The client MUST validate the server's response as follows:
>
> 1. If the status code received from the server is not 101, the
>    client handles the response per HTTP [RFC2616] procedures.  In
>    particular, the client might perform authentication if it
>    receives a 401 status code; the server might redirect the client
>    using a 3xx status code (but clients are not required to follow
>    them), etc.

So, it's purely up to the client whether they want to support redirects or not and is clearly not something you can rely on unless you find in extensive testing that all relevant clients support it (which they apparently do not).

You will either have to go with something like a server-side proxy or a client-side scheme to manually move the connection to another server.

Answer (score 8):

It's been four years since this question has been asked so here's how you'd do it today:

### in npm `ws` package:

set `followRedirects` to `true` in your socket client constructor ([source](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/d2c935a477fa6999c8fa85b89dfae27b85b807e7/doc/ws.md?plain=1#L272)).

### in `wscat` utility:

pass the `-L` flag ([source](https://github.com/websockets/wscat/blob/a9902a83a8e702019baef901a946542b8d224f6f/README.md?plain=1#L33)).

### in "most" browsers:

If you don't care about semantics, I [wrote a package](https://github.com/3p3r/websocket-redirect-shim) for this. otherwise it is possible to switch the URL in WebSocket's constructor by hooking into its constructor and eventually support a redirect response.

```js
'use strict';

/* global window, WebSocket*/

(function (WebSocketNative = window.WebSocket) {
  const debug = console.log;
  debug('patching native WebSocket class to support HTTP redirects');
  window.WebSocket = class {
    constructor(url, ...args) {
      this.work = [];
      this.endpoint = url.replace(/^http/, 'ws');
      debug('ws constructed with url: "%s" and endpoint: "%s"', url, this.endpoint);
      return (
        (async () => {
          try {
            const resolver =
              window.WEBSOCKET_REDIRECT_RESOLVER || `${location.protocol}//${location.host}${location.pathname}`;
            debug('websocket address resolver: "%s"', resolver);
            const endpoint = `${resolver}?url=${encodeURIComponent(this.endpoint)}`;
            debug('resolver query endpoint: "%s"', endpoint);
            const response = await fetch(endpoint);
            debug('resolver query response: "%o"', response);
            const { dig, dug } = await response.json();
            debug('resolver dig: "%o" dug: "%o"', dig, dug);
            this.endpoint = dug;
          } finally {
            debug('websocket final endpoint: "%s"', this.endpoint);
            this.socket = new WebSocketNative(this.endpoint, ...args);
            debug('flushing %d queued operations', this.work.length);
            for (const op of this.work) op(this.socket);
          }
        })(),
        new Proxy(this, {
          get: function (target, prop) {
            debug('GETTER trace: "%s"', prop);
            switch (prop) {
              case 'construct':
              case 'endpoint':
              case 'socket':
              case 'work':
                debug('GETTER "%s" does not go through proxy', prop);
                return Reflect.get(...arguments);
              case 'OPEN':
              case 'CLOSED':
              case 'CLOSING':
              case 'CONNECTING':
                debug('GETTER "%s" is a static', prop);
                return Reflect.get(WebSocketNative, prop);
              case 'readyState':
              case 'bufferedAmount':
                return this.socket ? Reflect.get(this.socket, prop) : 0;
              case 'binaryType':
                return this.socket ? Reflect.get(this.socket, prop) : 'blob';
              case 'extensions':
              case 'protocol':
              case 'url':
                return this.socket ? Reflect.get(this.socket, prop) : '';
              default:
                return this.socket
                  ? Reflect.get(this.socket, prop)
                  : function (...args) {
                      if (target.socket) {
                        debug('socket is ready, skip queueing get "%s" with args "%o"', prop, args);
                        return Reflect.get(target.socket, prop).call(target.socket, ...args);
                      } else {
                        debug('socket is not ready yet. queueing get "%s" with args "%o"', prop, args);
                        target.work.push((socket) => Reflect.get(socket, prop).call(socket, ...args));
                      }
                    };
            }
          },
          set: function (target, prop, value) {
            debug('SETTER trace: "%s"="%o"', prop, value);
            switch (prop) {
              case 'endpoint':
              case 'socket':
              case 'work':
                return Reflect.set(...arguments);
              default:
                return this.socket
                  ? Reflect.set(this.socket, prop, value)
                  : (() => {
                      if (target.socket) {
                        debug('socket is ready, skip queueing set "%s" with value "%o"', prop, value);
                        Reflect.set(socket, prop, value);
                      } else {
                        debug('socket is not ready yet, queueing set "%s" with value "%o"', prop, value);
                        target.work.push((socket) => Reflect.set(socket, prop, value));
                      }
                      return true;
                    })();
            }
          },
        })
      );
    }
  };
})(window.WebSocket);
```

This snippet overrides browser's native WebSocket class with one that supports switching the URL to `ALTERNATE_WEBSOCKET_ADDRESS` on the fly. You need to define `ALTERNATE_WEBSOCKET_ADDRESS` somewhere as it's not possible to figure out a redirect response's eventual URL in a browser environment (neither with `fetch`, nor with `XMLHttpRequest`). `fetch` is only used to detect a redirect. You need to come up with a mechanism to have `ALTERNATE_WEBSOCKET_ADDRESS` ready when time comes to a redirect.