# Is it possible to redirect an HTTP upgrade request to another URL?

Tags: node.js, http, redirect, websocket, http-1.1

When getting a WebSocket upgrade request in Node.js, is it possible to redirect it to another URL?

Comment: Close to the same question: [Is it possible to seamlessly redirect websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962881/is-it-possible-to-seamlessly-redirect-websockets).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to seamlessly redirect websockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962881/is-it-possible-to-seamlessly-redirect-websockets)