# Is it possible to hand-off a websocket connection request to a different service?

Tags: python, nginx, web, websocket, fastapi

Does the web socket protocol allow for a server web-socket endpoint to indicate to a client to attempt the connection elsewhere? I suppose this would be the equivalent of an HTTP redirect.

If the protocol doesn't allow it, is there a common way to use an intermediary service to allocate web-sockets dynamically between servers?

If it helps narrow the scope, I'm mostly interested in techniques using the Python FastAPI tools or nginx.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986351/1557060) answer your question?

Comment: In short: it is up to the client to handle responses of a 3XX kind. From a server point of view, it is valid to respond with a HTTP redirect on a websocket. It is up to the client to follow the redirect or not.