# Handle Multiple Websocket Connection w Different URL

Tags: node.js, websocket, containers

I'm trying to build an application in node.js that allows users to connect to containers through web socket connection, but the application must support multiple users' connection to different web socket sessions (different ws url). The diagram looks like this.

[image]

As a said, the app must be in node.js. I'm reading/studying both web socket and socket.io libraries. But I couldn't figure it out. Does anybody have any article or book to recommend?

What I want is similar to this:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8000 });

wss.on('connection', (client) => {
  const serverUrl = 'wss://for-user-1.com';
  const server = new WebSocket(serverUrl);

  client.on('message', (clientData) => {
    // Forward data from the client to the server
    server.send(clientData);
  });

  server.on('message', (serverData) => {
    // Forward data from the server to the client
    client.send(serverData);
  });

  client.on('close', () => {
    // Close the server connection when the client connection is closed
    server.close();
  });

  server.on('close', () => {
    // Close the client connection when the server connection is closed
    client.close();
  });

  client.on('message', (clientData) => {
    console.log('Received message from client:', clientData);
    // Process client message here
  });

  server.on('message', (serverData) => {
    console.log('Received message from server:', serverData);
    // Process server message here
  });
});
```

But in this code, I have just one websocket connection. How can I manage multiple websocket connections?

In my diagram, for instance, user 1 is connected to container 1, user 2 to container 2, and so on... how the WS Server will handle it?

Comment: Does this post help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962881/is-it-possible-to-seamlessly-redirect-websockets

Comment: @theknightD2 kind of.. still doesn't answer how to handle multiple websocket connections. In my diagram, por instance, user1 is connected to container 1, user 2 to container 2 and so on... how the WS Server will handle it?